# \alph without counters

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, numbering, counters, foreach

When I iterate numbers with TikZ `\foreach`, they are stored in a macro. Now, when I need the letter corresponding to this macro, I can only convert it by saving it to a counter and then receiving it again.

```
\foreach \n in {1,...,10} {
  \setcounter{number}{\n}
  \edef\letter{\alph{number}}
}
```

Directly issuing

```
\alph{\n}
```

does not work. I think it would be more efficient to avoid the counter. Is it possible convert directly?

Comment: [Using \Alph on \foreach loop argument](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42783)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\alph` expects a counter following it.

But you could resort to using clues from the internal meaning of `\alph`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\makeatletter
\def\aeAlph#1{\@alph{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {1,...,10}{
  \edef\letter{\aeAlph{\n}}
  Letter=\letter\par
}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Calling `texdef -t latex alph` from the command line gives you

```
\alph:
macro:#1->\expandafter \@alph \csname c@#1\endcsname
```

which tells you that `\alph` takes the name of a counter and "looks up" its value via `\csname c@#1\endcsname` which is LaTeX's way of storing counter values.

Comment: no need for `\expandafter`: `\edef\letter{\@alph{\n}}` will do

Comment: @cgnieder Just fixed that.

Comment: When the code exported to a package nonetheless, there is even no need to `\makeatletter`, so `\alph` can just be replaced directly with its @-variant.

Comment: @XZS I'm not sure what context you're using this in.  If you remove the `\makeatletter` business from my MWE, it will fail.  If you're in a package, then most likely `\makeatletter` has already been called; and then, as you say, it's not necessary (or even possibly destructive if you include the `\makeatother`).

Comment: @A.Ellett `\foreach\n in{1,...,10}{Letter=\aeAlph{\n}\par}` is sufficient: why the `\edef`?

Comment: @egreg I used `\edef` only because the OP's MWE used an `\edef`.

Comment: @A.Ellett (sorry, slightly off topic): where does "texdef" come from? My machine says "command not found"

Comment: @Harry It's a command line tool available on Mac and Linux systems.  If you're on the PC with Windows, I don't know how you access it.